# Why did Mayer drop his hanky in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In *Mank* (2020), after attending Thalberg's funeral, crying Mayer gets into the car and drops his hanky from a car window:

[image]

The shot was focused on it as there is a hidden meaning in it. Why did he drop his hanky in this scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [it is an act](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Mank):

> Crocodile Tears: Mayer is guilty of this twice:
>
> - Early in the film, he gives a tearful speech to his MGM employees, claiming the studio is about to go broke and asking them to take a 50% pay cut for eight weeks. **After the employees are moved by his tears and agree to his proposal, he walks offstage and congratulates himself on his performance, smirking at his aides.**
> - After weeping openly at Thalberg's funeral, Mayer casually discards his handkerchief out the car window.